# How do I break walls as Protoss?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I often play 2v2 or 3v3 as Protoss and I often rely on my teammates to break walls.

A lot of 2v2/3v3 have common base and entry for each team, which is typically walled.
In **early game**, as Protoss, I don't how to efficiently/safely break a wall. And if there are some marines/roaches/stalkers behind the wall, that's bad luck for my zealots.

Zergs can use banlings, Terran have their long range tank.
What with Protoss? Tempests?

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessarily a good idea to break a wall. A wall is one strong way to use the defender's advantage, and there is no guarantee that you have the tools to break it "efficiently / safely". Also **there is also less reward for breaking a wall with Protoss** than if you're Zerg.

On maps like Scorched Haven where it's popular to mutually wall-off on the low ground, baneling busts are popular because a low-ground wall-off sacrifices high ground vision, which banelings are weak against, but lets you use buildings as part of your defense, which banelings are exceptionally strong against. In this scenario, banelings are the right tool for the job.

And once the wall is broken, Zerg wants to stream in lings to attack all mineral lines, keep the wall open, and intercept producing reinforcements. Baneling busts are a calculated decision based on the scenario, taking advantage of specific weaknesses in the opponent's defense, and a strong follow-up that's unique to Zerg.

If you are Protoss, you have different tools at your disposal. Instead of copying Zerg techniques and busting a wall, you have warp gate, warp prisms, blink... Use an allied overlord or floating building to get high-ground vision and warp in as you wish. This can be used to break a wall, by **distracting enemy forces away from the wall**.

Another way is to get fast blink, and just blink past a wall. Very risky but if you know it's safe (for example if they relocate their army to deal with a threat from your ally), it can be strong to go in, do damage, pick off a researching tech lab, a couple workers, and blink out.

Specifically for Protoss breaking walls:

1. **Forcefields** to prevent repairing and keep the army away while you break the wall (though if you have a zerg ally, make sure you don't forcefield his units out!).
2. **Zealots** are quite strong against buildings, especially in conjunction with siege tanks or roaches. Your opponents can't attack the zealots without getting in range of your ally's tanks. If your ally is baneling busting though please don't block the banelings with your zealots :)
3. **Stalkers** have range and speed to help more in DPS, and if you must retreat you can still keep your expensive units.
4. If your ally has tanks, then you certainly have enough time to get out an **immortal** or two. They are extremely efficient at killing buildings

Of course if you have immortals you may as well have an **observer for high ground vision**, or a **warp prism** even better.

Protoss can also ***prevent* the opponent from walling off** the easiest. For example if your Zerg ally goes for a very early pool, put a pylon in the opponent's intended wall, and cancel it. This keeps an open gate for your early lings to enter.

**tl;dr**: Protoss's toolbox is not well-suited for breaking walls. Protoss is instead better at circumventing a wall entirely. Depending on the scenario and your ally's race, give them a couple zealots to help busting a wall, or a couple forcefields, but focus your efforts on more efficient tasks - protecting your ally's precious few tanks, warping in and harassing elsewhere... Just don't lose sight of the goal. Breaking a wall as P or T, you don't really gain much because you can't stream in units like Zerg.

Comment: You totally makes sense. My problem is that not being able to break a wall, i can't put an end to my ennemy high tech. So while i've spend lots to get a decent army in early game, if i can't do damage with it because of a strong wall, that's almost a loss. Are you suggesting that i soon as i see a wall, i invest into a prism or blink to circle it ?

Comment: Yes, if you insist on being aggressive. I think the most effective early aggression is one that also gets a good scout. This gives you the best follow-up if your aggression doesn't kill them. This is also why I think breaking the wall is not as desirable to doing in-base harassment like with a warp prism and just a couple zealots.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how Protoss works vs Terran:

Depending on your build you can be most effective at around 7-8 minutes if you go for a 3 or 4 Gate timing. Your main goal is to bust through the wall. If you can achieve this  with minimal losses you win. Naturally this is very hard to do, otherwise Protoss would be way overpowered. There are certain builds where you cannot crush your opponents wall, like a 2 Rax expand with 1-2 bunkers. You have to scout this as this might result in a Build Order loss for you. Investing in a 4 gate and dealing no damage at all usually leaves you very vulnerable later on.

In the midgame (9-16 minutes) Protoss gets weaker, as they do not have their tech up and have to still rely on Gateway units. Upgraded Barracks units, especially with Medivacs, destroy Gateway units. But once you have a few Immortal and / or Collosi you can easily bust down walls. But in the midgame you have to stay in your base and defend potential timing pushes.

Once you are in the lategame and have your "Ball" you can push out again and secure your victory.

Having said that here are some drawbacks the other races struggle with:

- Banelings die if they destroy a wall. So if you do not have enough other units or the opponent is able wall in time again you die. This is an allin attack, at least in the early game.
- Tanks are Tier 2, so if you want to get them in the early game you need to go 2 gas before Factory and you end up with less units. So if the opponent catches you before you siege up you will die. An early Tank push is quite risky. Once sieged up they get very strong though. If your opponent knows what you are trying to do he will approach you with some of his units and you will have to siege up in the middle of the map. If you take too long leaping forward to his base he will crush you with his army.

In the end if you want to bust down a wall in the earlygame you have to invest in way more units than your opponent and commit to your attack. This is called an allin. Usually this involves Zealots, Stalker and depending on the wall a few Sentries. If you bust through you win if he holds you lose.

This assumes both players can execute their build orders equally good and the defending Terran wants to fast expand.